# paintbrush or mspaint executable file?

Tags: windows

When did `pbrush.exe` become `mspaint.exe`?

What was it in *Win98*? *Win95*? *Windows 3.1*? (no doubt *Win 3.1* it was *pbrush.exe*...)

I doubt I'm imagining things, it *was* `pbrush.exe` at one time. I'd like to know when the transition happened.

Also, when did the whole application get renamed from *paintbrush* to *mspaint*? Did the executable change with it at the same time?

---

**ADDED Jul 5 '11**:

MaxMackie [mentioned](https://superuser.com/a/306542/129520) this which is an interesting page and answers it.

http://blog.jonschneider.com/2007/06/mystery-of-phantom-pbrushexe-file.html

> From some newsgroup posts that I came across while researching this
>   issue, apparently on Windows 9x series machines (e.g. Windows 98), a
>   pbrush.exe file actually was included in the system32 directory that
>   was just a stub which executed mspaint.exe. (In even older Windows
>   versions, pbrush.exe was the 16-bit version of the Paint program; the
>   32-bit version, mspaint.exe, was apparently introduced with Windows
>   95.)
>
> For the 32-bit Windows NT series, an engineer at Microsoft must have
>   decided to switch the pbrush command from working via the actual
>   pbrush.exe stub file to taking advantage of the
>   HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths registry key.

Comment: what could I do to re-open this? it was useful to me.

Comment: @naxa don't know, but fortunately I don't think questions necessarily lose much value from being "closed". It's still there(not deleted thankfully) and if there's anything to add to the question or to an answer, then you could add a comment.. the fact that new answers can't be posted won't kill it.

Comment: won't closed questions be eventually deleted? from time to time I couldn't find bookmarked closed questions, says 404... stackprinter being half-way dedicated to saveing closed SO pages... are you sure this will stay, and how do you know?

Comment: @naxa That is a good point, I hadn't thought of that.  I just searching it on archive.org wasn't there initially but it let me add it to the wayback machine, https://web.archive.org/web/20131119101011/http://superuser.com/questions/306540/paintbrush-or-mspaint-executable-file   Other than that, one could store it locally -one reason why I sometimes like to have a link in there literally is so I or anyone can copy/paste it easily. Often if i'm looking at a program like wget, and I see a question with something useful, or anything online.. I might copy/paste parts into a wget.txt file.

Comment: @naxa  So, while it may be worth saving closed questions you find useful..(though that can be an issue as there's graphics, you may get a long filename/folder name if not careful with saving.. and it may be multi page like those great ones that were closed and deleted).It may be worth having files on programs and perhaps, files on tasks.
There are many forums where I find useful info, and I will and have outlived lots of them but my own collection of notes lives with me, can be on an online backup, and has been more reliable than any forum.

Comment: I like saving useful pages. However public internet is for everyone and personal notes are only for the person... I wish the pages could live. Do you post some of your notes (that are not personal)? I tend not to but slowly working myself towards having a blog or something... But that's while I'm interested in how to re-word the question so it can be re-opened, because then SO would archive the information publicly as long as it exists. Re-wording might help and it also improves the quality.

Comment: By the way, superuser should have a history tag for questions like this. :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11581/discussion-between-barlop-and-naxa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first version of Paint was introduced with the first version of Windows, Windows 1.0. It was a licensed version of ZSoft Corporation's **PC Paintbrush**. Paint was later renamed to Paintbrush in Windows 3.0, but the name was changed back to Paint in Windows 95 and later. This version only supported the MSP and BMP file formats. The former is no longer supported by newer versions of Paint, along with PCX and RLE. Older versions cannot open or edit PNG files, and can only open GIF, JPEG, and TIFF files with a graphics filter for the specific file type.

Comment: what about the executable name.  what was it, in the different windows versions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was still pbrush.exe. I know that in XP pbrush.exe was still around and it was mapped to mspaint.exe

Comment: your guess is slightly incorrect.  i'm on win xp sp3 right now, pbrush.exe is not in xp, but start..run..pbrush brings up mspaint.  but doing pbrush from the command prompt does not bring it up. on a related note there is a write.exe that brings up wordpad. What was the situation with paintbrush in win98 and 95?

Comment: Check this blog post out about the pbrush.exe phantom executable. http://blog.jonschneider.com/2007/06/mystery-of-phantom-pbrushexe-file.html. It also explains (in the last paragraph) the older history of the application.

Comment: Glad that blog post was helpful. :-)

Comment: @MaxMackie could you add the info from the link to the answer? Bringing it on-site is encouraged by StackEXchange.

Comment: @naxa yep, though it's ok in that it's on the site, I quoted info from his link in an edit I made to my question, so as to include it. I did that when he posted it.